# How to implement continuous migration for large website?

Tags: content-management-system, migration, cdn, continuous

I am working on a website of 3,000+ pages that is updated on a daily basis. It's already built on an open source CMS. However, we cannot simply continue to apply hot fixes on a regular basis. We need to replace the entire system and I anticipate the need to replace the entire system on a 1-2 year basis. We don't have the staff to work on a replacement system while the other is being worked on, as it results in duplicate effort. We also cannot have a "code freeze" while we work on the new site.

So, this amounts to changing the tire while driving. Or fixing the wings while flying. Or all sorts of analogies.

This brings me to a concept called "continuous migration." I read this article here: https://www.acquia.com/blog/dont-wait-migrate-drupal-continuous-migration

The writer's suggestion is to use a CDN like Fastly. The idea is that a CDN allows you to switch between a legacy system and a new system on a URL basis. This idea, in theory, sounds like a great idea that would work. This article claims that you can do this with Varnish but Fastly makes the job easier. I don't work much with Varnish, so I can't really verify its claims.

I also don't know if this is a good idea or if there are better alternatives. I looked at Fastly's pricing scheme, and I simply cannot translate what it means to a specific price point. I don't understand these cryptic cloud-service pricing plans, they don't make sense to me. I don't know what kind of bandwidth the website uses. Another agency manages the website's servers.

Can someone help me understand whether or not using an online CDN would be better over using something like Varnish? Is there free or cheaper solutions? Can someone tell me what this amounts to, approximately, on a monthly or annual basis? Any other, better ways to roll out a new website on a phased basis for a large website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not have the exact answers to your question but may be my answer helps a little bit.

I don't think that the CDN gives you an advantage. It is that you have more than one system.

### Changes to the code

In professional environments I'm used to have three different CMS installations. The fist is the development system, usually on my PC. That system is used to develop the extensions, fix bugs and so on supported by unit-tests. The code is committed to a revision control system (like SVN, CVS or Git). A continuous integration system checks the commits to the RCS. When feature is implemented (or some bugs are fixed) a named tag will be created. Then this tagged version is installed on a test-system where developers, customers and users can test the implementation. After a successful test exactly this tagged version will be installed on the production system.

A first sight this looks time consuming. But it isn't because most of the steps can be automated. And the biggest advantage is that the customer can test the change on a test system. And it is very unlikely that an error occurs only on your production system. (A precondition is that your systems are build on a similar/equal environment. )

### Changes to the content

If your code changes the way your content is processed it is an advantage when your 
CMS has strong workflow support. Than you can easily add a step to your workflow 
which desides if the content is old and has to be migrated for the current document.
This way you have a continuous migration of the content.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Varnish is a cache rather than a CDN.  It intercepts page requests and delivers a cached version if one exists.

A CDN will serve up contents (images, JS, other resources etc) from an off-server location, typically in the cloud.

The cloud-based solutions pricing is often very cryptic as it's quite complicated technology.

I would be careful with continuous migration.  I've done both methods in the past (continuous and full migrations) and I have to say, continuous is a pain.  It means double the admin time for everything, and assumes your requirements are the same at all points in time.

Unfortunately, I would say you're better with a proper rebuilt on a 1-2 year basis than a continuous migration, but obviously you know best about that.

I would suggest you maybe also consider a hybrid approach?  Build yourself an export tool to keep all of your content in a transferrable state like CSV/XML/JSON so you can just import into a new system when ready.  This means you can incorporate new build requests when you need them in a new system (what's the point in a new system if it does exactly the same as the old one) and you get to keep all your content.  Plus you don't need to build and maintain two CMS' all the time.